# select all elements with CSS if there are exactly 5

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want all 5 children IF there are EXACTLY 5. (If there are 4 or 6, don't select ANY children.)

To illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/339H6/3/show/

You can select all elements if there are 1 very simply:

```
:first-child:last-child
```

You can select elements that are in the first 5 AND last 5:

```
:nth-child(-n+5):nth-last-child(-n+5)
```

(red in the demo) Both don't do what I want, but illustrate a point: 1 selector, several elements.

You can select all children IF there are 5 with 5 selectors:

```
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(5),
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4),
li:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(1)
```

(yellow in the fiddle) but that's horrible. It's doubly horrible when I decide I ALSO like 4: if there are exactly 4 OR 5 elements, select them all. That would require 4 more selectors.

Is there a decent way to do this that I'm missing? I feel like `:nth-child(-n+5):nth-last-child(-n+5)` is on track, but that selects way too broadly. (Green in the fiddle.)

Comment: Note that `:first-child:last-child` can simply be represented as `:only-child` if specificity is not an issue (2 pseudo-classes versus 1).

Comment: I was trying to show how you can make a selection with a double pseudo selector. `nth-child(1)` is special like that, but I was hoping for something for 5 etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the general sibling combinator to select the rest of the elements after determining that the first child is also the 5th last child:

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(5), 
li:first-child:nth-last-child(5) ~ li
```

You'll still have to repeat the selector at least once, unfortunately, as you need one to match the first child, then another with the sibling combinator to match the rest. But it definitely beats repeating it four more times.

Comment: That's pretty damn smart! That `+` and `~` are so weird and brilliant!